# Query to update duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, sql-update

I have the following query that returns duplicates that i am running on sql server. So I need to write a query that will update second instance of the email address based on the select query that retrieves dulicates to for example 
imports@rohnis.com to imports@rohnis.com.duplicate. If it is info@eps.ws then info@eps.ws.duplicate. So basically postfix 
the email address with the word duplicate. It could be any email address

Query to search duplicates

```
SELECT ta.Id
      ,ta.Email
      ,ta.ClientCompanyId

FROM [IdentityDB_CSR].[dbo].[User] ta
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM [IdentityDB_CSR].[dbo].[User] ta2
       WHERE ta.Email=ta2.Email
       AND ta.ClientCompanyId=ta2.ClientCompanyId)>1
```

Output of the query

[image]

Query to update

```
update [IdentityDB_CSR].[dbo].[User]
  set Email = 'info@eps.ws.duplicate'
  where id = 87183
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an updatable cte:

```
with cte as (
    select
        Email,
        row_number() over(partition by Email, ClientCompanyId order by id desc) rn
    from [IdentityDB_CSR].[dbo].[User]
)
update cte 
set Email = Email + '.duplicate'
where rn > 1
```

This identifies duplicates as record that share the same `Email` and `ClientCompanyId`. The record that has the greatest `id` is left untouched, while for others we add `'.duplicate` at the end of the `Email`.

Comment: Great! https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d0aee7b6615f562d05e01705ea64ac50

Comment: I upvoted, but there is still [flaws](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce33c74e8020b459d98542b844f2c5ff). When there is 3 or more the same entry (This may be required in fact)

Comment: Well - it looks ok to me when that hapends... : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ce33c74e8020b459d98542b844f2c5ff